# Are within- and across-chain averages equivalent in Markov chain Monte-Carlo simulation?

Tags: physics, markov-chains, markov-process, monte-carlo, simulation

I am not very familiar with math notations so please bear with me.

Let's imagine that I repeat the same chain $N$ times to estimate quantity $a$. Let's also imagine that I acquire $M$ samples per chain, after a copious burn-in period (to let the simulation reach steady-state).

For the sake of discussion, $N = M$ and the samples within each chains are supposed to be independent.

Then **would taking the average value of $a$ over a single chain and the average value of $a$ at a single iteration point across the chains be similar?** (i.e. would they be expected to follow the same distribution?).

I am asking because in some cases, these definitions do not *seem* equivalent: $a$ is very consistent if I average within chains but I know that the values within the chain are only weakly independent. At the same time, averaging across chains (at a given iteration number) provides inconsistent results but the individual values are guaranteed to be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property that long-time averages of a single trajectory converge to ensemble averages against the stationary distribution as time goes on is called *ergodicity* of the chain. Sufficient conditions for ergodicity are known, and are usually satisfied in applications.

Of course the two are not the same if you only run the chain for some finite amount of time (which we always do). That is, ergodicity is only about convergence. A context-dependent issue is the convergence *rate*, which can potentially be quite slow (e.g. in the presence of metastability effects). Finite time averages will also not follow exactly the same distribution as finite ensemble averages.

Comment: I understand what  you say (I think), but do averages across chains (e.g. calculated by averaging the respective value found at the 10000000th iteration in each chain) guaranteed to converge to the ensemble average too?

Comment: @Will Unless you continue to move the sampling point further forward in time, no. They will converge to the ensemble average against the distribution of $X_{10000000}$ which is generally somewhat different from the stationary distribution. The extent of this difference depends on the convergence rate; it could be negligible or it could be significant.

Comment: Ah! But if that value is very large versus correlation time and equilibration time, it the distribution of $X_n$ should follow the stationary distribution then, shouldn't it? (At least in the same extent as the time average)

Comment: @Will Not *exactly*, no. Just close. For example, given a distribution of $X_0$ you can exactly calculate the distribution of $X_t$ with the transition matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0.25 & 0.75 \\ 0.4 & 0.6 \end{bmatrix}$. But unless $X_0$ was exactly distributed like the stationary distribution, the distribution of $X_n$ will not quite be stationary no matter how big $n$ is. On the other hand, in this example the discrepancy will be on the order of $(0.15)^n$ (0.15 being the magnitude of the second eigenvalue of this matrix), and soon enough that is just too small to matter.

Comment: @Will (Cont.) When that "soon enough" is is hopefully about the same as your burn-in period. If the burn-in period is shorter, then you're seeing residual effects of the initial distribution; if the burn-in period is longer then you're throwing away perfectly good data.